# Convert Int to Hex rgb

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am receiving a color value in an integer format, such as *2232780* for the hex value `#2211CC`.
How can I convert this `unsigned integer` to a `QString` of the hex value, like `QString val = "#2211CC"`,
so that I can pass it to my QML item and bind it with the `color` property?

```
color: model.colorVal
```

Comment: [`QString("#%1").arg(value, 6, 16, '0')`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg-2)?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, it is probably sufficient to only mention the documentation. [`QColor(2232780)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcolor.html#QColor-3)[`.name()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcolor.html#name) returns the color in *hex string*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `QColor` instead of `QString`:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor NOTIFY colorChanged)
```

And set it like this:

```
setColor(QColor::fromRgb(0x2211CC));
```